# Handbrake on Debian not aware of x265 despite installed

Tags: debian, video-encoding, handbrake

I am about to convert a lot of old [MKV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) files encoded with [x264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264), which at the moment are un-downloadable, to more efficient [HEVC (x265, H.265)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) format, using [HandBrake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HandBrake) software.

My system being Debian Jessie 8.6, fully updated.

I have installed `handbrake` and `x265` packages from official repositories.

The problem is, I can't seem to be able to choose [x265](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) in [HandBrake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HandBrake).

On Linux Mint 18, there is no problem, it's just there.

On Debian 8.6, there is a package called `handbrake`, on Linux Mint 18 I have added a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases) and installed `handbrake-gtk`.

Versions seem to matter in this case:

Debian: **0.9.9 (x86_64)**

Mint: **0.10.5 (x86_64)**

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro You may safely delete the comment. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the Debian Jessie `handbrake` version, which is '0.9.9', and quite old in the style that Debian got us used.

Having a look at the official HandBrake site, in the [news](https://handbrake.fr/news.php) section they state:

> - v0.10.5 - Few minor bug fixes since the 0.10.3 release. This includes improvements in large AVI file handling.
> - v0.10.3 - Updated x265 to 1.8 which brings numerous bug fixes and some performance improvements.

So I would say you need at least 0.10.3, and would advise 0.10.5.

Unfortunately, there are no new packages in backports; - I would either try to install it from the Ubuntu PPA if the dependencies do not do something funny, or compile it by hand. Give it a try to the PPA first.

According to https://packages.debian.org/, stretch/Debian 9 already brings 0.10.5 with Debian patches - if in a pre-production/home server, I would recommend upgrading to Stretch.

As for compiling it in Jessie, see [How To Install HandBrake 0.9.9 On Debian Jessie, Debian Sid And Debian Wheezy](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-handbrake-0-9-9-on-debian-jessie-debian-sid-and-debian-wheezy/)